# Using sed on a special character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, command

currently I have a file 
that contains the text
`Your path: ../test/tester [hello] whatever`
But I want to change it to: `Your path: ../../tested/text [hello] whatever`
I've tried sed but I believe ../ is a special character so I'm not too sure how to approach this problem.

This won't work for me.
 sed `s/tester/..//g;s/tester/tested/text/`

Comment: Use a different separator.

Comment: I followed that guide but I still get bad substitution
sed "s|\test|${../tested}|" myfile

Comment: Not sure what you're trying but something like `s|../test/tester|../../tested/text|` would work.

Comment: `${../tested}` doesn't make any sense, it would result in an error.  Maybe you want to say `../${tested}` instead.

Comment: And why are you escaping `test` in the pattern?  `sed "s|test|../${tested}|" myfile`

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
➜  scripts  cat example
Your path: ../test/tester [hello] whatever

➜  scripts  sed "s|../test/tester|../../tested/text|" example > example2
➜  scripts  cat example2
Your path: ../../tested/text [hello] whatever
```